# heroku deployment failed remote rejected ngtw not found

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I tried to deploy my MEAN stack web app to heroku, but the build fails and shows: `sh1: ngtw not found`

```
      Build
   Running build
   
   > build-pro-web-app@0.0.0 build /tmp/build_4bae0d31_
   > ngtw build && ng build
   
sh: 1: ngtw: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! build-pro-web-app@0.0.0 build: `ngtw build && ng build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the build-pro-web-app@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR!
```

This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.